# Significance of Flash scene in BvS

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

What is the significance of the Flash scene in *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice*?

In one scene it looks like Batman was dreaming where Flash comes and says

> Bruce! Listen to me right now! It’s Lois! Lois Lane! She’s the key! Am I too soon!? I'm too soon! You were right about him! You were always right about him! Fear him! Fear him and find us. You have to come find us, Bruce!

Comment: At the moment we don't know...supposition is that it will *somehow* link into **future** movies. - https://www.cinemablend.com/new/What-Actually-Happening-Crazy-Flash-Scene-From-Dawn-Justice-120907.html

Comment: I thought they were going to clarify that in Justice League, but they didn't. :P

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Because Joss Whedon happen

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir , I have an alternate answer [ https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/92196/58619 ] where I feel that Justice League did clarify that partially.